# Iterate/Loop through all folders of directory h5 files

Tags: python, loops, operating-system

I am working with the popular million song dataset and the data is contained in several nested subfolders. All the files are .h5 files. I am using the os library to import the data into python, but it stops at the parent folder and doesn't loop through to get all the data. I'm not sure how to build a loop to make that happen.

```
entries = os.listdir("/Users/katherineperkins/Downloads/MillionSongSubset/data")



for filename in os.listdir(entries):
if filename.endswith(".h5") or filename.endswith(".py"): 
     # print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
    continue
else:
    continue
```

With all the snippets I've found, I end up getting the following error:

`listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike, integer or None, not list`

Comment: loop on `entries` (joined with your absolute path)

Answer (score 0):

`entries` is a list of (directory?) names. `os.listdir` cannot take them as a parameter at the same time. You need an outer loop, and the inner loop needs joining the entry with the directory it's been scanned from.

```
root_dir = "/Users/katherineperkins/Downloads/MillionSongSubset/data"
for entry in os.listdir(root_dir):
   for filename in os.listdir(os.path.join(root_dir,entry)):
          if filename.endswith((".h5",".py")): 
              # do something: beware as filename isn't the full filepath.
              # it needs joining with os.path.join(root_dir,entry)
```

The above code works unless `entry` is *not* a directory. We could test for directory, or catch the exception, or maybe at some point switch to `glob` with a 2-level "all-file" wildcard, which is much simpler

```
import glob

for filepath in glob.glob("/Users/katherineperkins/Downloads/MillionSongSubset/data/*/*"):
      if filepath.endswith((".h5",".py")): 
          # do something
```

testing the file extension with `endswith` (which accepts a `tuple` by the way) is less costly than using `glob.glob` on both extensions (ex: `glob.glob("/Users/katherineperkins/Downloads/MillionSongSubset/data/*/*.h5")` (would need 2 directory scans)

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful! It's a little confusing because sometimes when I try certain code it calls root_dir a directory and sometimes it says it's not. When I tried your code for the os.listdir it said it wasn't, but the glob code seems to have worked! I also realized my larger problem is that I'm not sure what to put in the if statement to be able to view that data. Do you happen to have a recommendation for that? That's what I'm trying to do ultimately. I'm sorry for all the fundamental questions, but this is a school project and my first time working with this type of data.